# Using ArrayList class in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I tried to use ArrayList class in Xamarin, even I added **System.Collections** NuGet, but still compiler doesn't recognize **ArrayList** class.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the exact code and errors you are getting

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to use `ArrayList` from a PCL. `ArrayList` is not available for PCLs. Isn't `List` sufficient for your needs?

Comment: You are right! Maybe I should use List, but generally how can I access classes which are not packed in PCL? I should create a new PCL?